# .jar file not opening after changing environment variables (only opens through command line)

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable-jar

After changing `JAVA_HOME` to jdk-11, the `PATH` to the bin in that folder, and removing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` from `PATH` I tried to open a .jar file by double clicking on it but it showed this prompt: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCOFB.png) (saying *How do you want to open this .jar file?* with *Keed using this app* as *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %** .

I tried going to *More apps* and selecting the `javaw.exe` from the new `jdk-11` bin and also from the `java.exe` but neither did anything seemingly. It seems like it is trying to open the .jar file the way it was opening it before with the other jre but how do I update it to use the new PATH or JAVA_HOME instead now to open .jar files. I was able to run it from cmd inputting `java -jar ....` (with the ... being the file path).

Through this I know that it is feasible to create a batch file to run it but is there any way to make my system run .jar files by just double clicking on it like it used to before I changed my jre to the one found in jdk-11? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out, this link kinjd of shows where the registry key for the java jar file is, but I wouldn't recommend actually following the steps on it if you just need to change the registry key: https://appuals.com/how-to-run-jar-files-on-windows-10/ but if you use it, you should probably use it to find where Java is in the registry key. In that vain, mine was a little different compared to the guide. For me I went into registry edit and went to `jarfile` going down to the `shell` then `open` then modifying `command` setting it to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` with the first part in parenthesis being whatever your path for the jre executable is.

I hope this helps anyone who had the same problem as I did!

Comment: @user15358848 I didn't really follow the link, I only used it to figure out where (kind of) the jarfile was in the registry key, the rest of it I did not use.